# How to display 2 JFrames in 2 different displays in Java?

Tags: java, linux, awt, awtrobot, xorg

This sample of code gives me the available screens for the current display:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
```

But what I want to do is have a JFrame on different displays. (Different xorg servers running on the same physical computer).

Example.

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
java myapp
```

This will show a popup in display 0.0 on any of the screens available.

```
export DISPLAY=:1.0
java myapp
```

This will show a popup in display 1.0 on any of the screens available

Now, what if I want to have one in display 1.0 and one in display 0.0 from the same application, what ever screen it is.

Basically, I want my application to run mainly with export DISPLAY=:1.0 but I want a status JFrame to be displayed in :0.0. How can I achieve that in Java? Any idea? Or, if this is not possible, I want to have AWT robot running in DISPLAY:1.0 and AWT displays in DISPLAY=:0.0

Do not confuse this with display 2 JFrames on 2 different screens from the same GraphicsEnvironment. That's easy and already replied. Here I'm talking about 2 JFrames on 2 different displays, each of them having 1 to x screens. So there is nothing in current question which is related to "java, show JFrame in a specific screen in dual monitor configuration". Please read carefully.

Example:
Display 0.0 has 2 screens. Device 1 and Device 2.
Display 1.0 is a VNC server display and has 1 screen. Device 1.

I want to display a JFrame on Display 0.0 device 2, and on display 1.0 device 1.

Getting all the devices for a single display is easy using getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(). But how can I get the other available displays and the related screens? Using bash command line I can using export DISPLAY to go to the one I want then use wmctrl to get the details. How can I do something similar with Java?

Update:
I have found the X servers in the filesystem using this:

```
cd /tmp/.X11-unix && for x in X*; do echo ":${x#X}"; done
```

But still not fond how to say to a specific Java window to be displayed on one or on another one...
Thanks.

Comment: Hum. I will be very interested to get the details from the people marking this as duplicate. You most probably mix this with simply display a JFrame in 2 different screens of the same display. Here I talk about 2 different displays, each of them can have 1 to x screens. If you still think it's a duplicate, please provide details and/or link because I did not found this anywhere in StackOverflow nor looking on Google...

Comment: Ok. I see that duplicates are refering to "java, show JFrame in a specific screen in dual monitor configuration " which is not at all related to current question. Please read the question again and take more time to understand the difference between 2 screens (devices) and 2 displays (2 graphics servers serving multiple screens/devices).